# Eclipse RCP AspectJ configure

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi, aspectj

I am trying to add AspectJ in my Eclipse RCP/RAP application.

I did step by step as these guys say: [link here](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php) (except creating a new platform, I added the libraries by my self in my platform).

But the problem is that it is still not working... I get this error:

```
osgi> !SESSION 2012-03-18 02:16:54.354 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_02
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:/home/alexandru/workspaces/Java-RCP-RAP/project/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/RAP Application/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -console -data /home/alexandru/workspaces/Java-RCP-RAP/project/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rap.ui.launch/RAPApplication

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-18 02:16:54.960
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook not found.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.definition.Definition
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingActivator.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

I don't know why I have this error... it's really strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well... this error happened because I haven't reexported the `org.aspectj.runtime` dependency...

but now I have another error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-03-18 21:33:55.112
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook not found.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingActivator.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/equinox/service/weaving/IWeavingServiceFactory
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingStarter.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.equinox.service.weaving.IWeavingServiceFactory
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 21 more
```

I think this is because `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` is not found... but I added this `-Dosgi.framework.extensions=org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` at `run configurations`.

**EDITED with SOLUTION:**

found it..

I had to add the aspectj libraries in the same folder where my osgi framework is (where platform is defined)

Comment: And they wonder why AOP never took off... great functionality to have but such a pain in the neck to get working.  Only the most stubborn survive!